# Making legend from layer in ArcGlobe

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, 3d-analyst, arcglobe

I want to make a legend on the layer. I heard that in ArcGIS there is a legend wizard, where you can make a legend, but it is in ArcMap, not ArcGlobe.

Is there any tool similar in ArcGlobe?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add dynamic text or legends in ArcGlobe as it does not contain a layout view, that we have in ArcMap.

If you are creating an animation, you can follow a workaround explained below.

To add a legend to an animation the only way is to export to a series of jpegs (images) instead of animation, then add a legend graphic to each of the images and use a video application like Windows Movie Maker to make a video from the images.

Comment: I just needed a legend, without animation I do, but thank you for the advice, it may come in handy someday